# Vkontakte API: загрузка видео со стороннего сервера

Tags: видео, vkontakte-api

Схема такая: IFrame-приложение, пользователь постит видеофайл через форму на СЕРВЕР; СЕРВЕР обрабатывает видео и загружает его на страничку пользователя ВКонтакте с помощью метода video.save (возможно, по сигналу от клиента).

Так вот: как сделать, чтобы это работало?

Пробовал делать video.save на клиенте, затем upload с сервера по полученному URL - получаю от nginx "Security Breach2". Пробую с сервера вызывать video.save - получаю "Unknown method passed". Качать файл с сервера на клиент и постить - не могу, у меня IFrame (да и вообще это нехорошо). Где же правильный путь? И есть ли он?

Answer (score 1):

Решением такое: на клиенте вызываем video.save, передаём полученный upload_url на сервер, грузим с сервера файл и обязательно передаём заголовок Referer, такой же, как в video.save.